# PHP RegExp Replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am currently trying to add tokens to a CMS using PHP.

The user can enter (into a WYSIWYG Editor) a string such as `[my_include.php]`. We would like to  extract anything with this format, and turn it into an include of the following format:

`include('my_include.php');`

Can anyone assist with composing the RegExp and extraction process to allow this? Ideally, I would like to extract them all into a single array, so that we can provide some checking before parsing it as the `include();`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_replace('~\[([^\]]+)\]~', 'include "\\1";', $str);
```

Working sample: http://ideone.com/zkwX7

Comment: @BenM For future reference, please edit additional code into your original question, not the comments. That way, it's nicely formatted and understandable so we can help you better.

Answer (score 2):

You'll either want to go with preg_match_all(), run the results in a loop and replace whatever you found. Might be a bit faster than the following callback solution, but is a bit more tricky if PREG_OFFSET_CAPUTRE and substr_replace() is used.

```
<?php

function handle_replace_thingie($matches) {
  // build a file path
  $file = '/path/to/' . trim($matches[1]);

  // do some sanity checks, like file_exists, file-location (not that someone includes /etc/passwd or something)
  // check realpath(), file_exists() 
  // limit the readable files to certain directories
  if (false) {
    return $matches[0]; // return original, no replacement
  }

  // assuming the include file outputs its stuff we need to capture it with an output buffer
  ob_start();
  // execute the include
  include $file;
  // grab the buffer's contents
  $res = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  // return the contents to replace the original [foo.php]
  return $res;
}

$string = "hello world, [my_include.php] and [foo-bar.php] should be replaced";
$string = preg_replace_callback('#\[([^\[]+)\]#', 'handle_replace_thingie', $string);
echo $string, "\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), you could do this:

```
$matches = array();

// If we've found any matches, do stuff with them
if(preg_match_all("/\[.+\.php\]/i", $input, $matches))
{
    foreach($matches as $match)
    {
        // Any validation code goes here

        include_once("/path/to/" . $match);
    }
}
```

The regex used here is `\[.+\.php\]`. This will match any `*.php` string so that if the user types `[hello]` for example, it won't match.